# How can I search for the value in the array that contains something?

Tags: php, json, google-maps-api-3, multidimensional-array

I have a JSON being returned from [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/) that I'd like to retrieve just the state / county / region, and the country.

I am getting this json via PHP using the following simple code:

```
$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=the+address&sensor=true&key=my+api+key';

// make the HTTP request
$data = @file_get_contents($url);

$jsondata = json_decode($data,true);
```

echoing $data gives me something like:

```
{
"results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "9",
           "short_name" : "9",
           "types" : [ "street_number" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Hanover Street",
           "short_name" : "Hanover St",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Edinburgh",
           "short_name" : "Edinburgh",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "City of Edinburgh",
           "short_name" : "City of Edinburgh",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Scotland",
           "short_name" : "Scotland",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United Kingdom",
           "short_name" : "GB",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "EH2",
           "short_name" : "EH2",
           "types" : [ "postal_code_prefix", "postal_code" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Edinburgh",
           "short_name" : "Edinburgh",
           "types" : [ "postal_town" ]
        }
     ]
  }
],
"status" : "OK"
}
```

What I'm wanting to access is inside the multidimensional array *address_components*, and I assumed each JSON response from Google would give me the same number of arrays each time and so I've been using simple number indexes to access the data I need.

i.e. I thought that something `$jsondata['results'][0]['address_components'][4]['long_name']` would always give me the long_name value of 'administrative_area_level_2' - in this case 'City of Edinburgh', but I was mistaken.

Sometimes there are more address components, and sometimes less. Which means I need a way of searching this array and then getting the index of it.

How is that done? As in, how do I search which address component has the type 'administrative_area_level_1' and then return the 'long_name' value of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can try is doing a `foreach` loop through the results doing a check for the data you need.  If you are specifically looking for the "administrative_area_level_1" inside one of the address components, you can check on it's `type`.

Something like this:

```
foreach ($jsondata['results'][0]['address_components'] as $comp) {
    //loop through each component in ['address_components']
    foreach ($comp['types'] as $currType){
        //for every type in the current component, check if it = the check
        if($currType == 'administrative_area_level_1'){
            echo $comp['long_name'];
            //Do whatever with the component, print longname, whatever you need
            //You can add $comp into another array to have an array of 'administrative_area_level_1' types
        }
    }
}
```

That should be looping/searching through that results set on a component by component level.  From there, you have a handle on a "current component" which you can do further logic/parsing on.  Inside that "current component" you have your "types" which you are checking against.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function to loop all over the arrays and return the required value, if it finds it.

```
$jsondata = json_decode($data, true);

function getAdministrativeAreaLevel2($addresses) {
    if (!is_array($addresses) || empty($addresses)) {
        return; // we need an array with data
    }

    foreach ($addresses as $address) {
        if (!isset($address['address_components']))
            continue; // nothing to look at
        foreach ($address['address_components'] as $compontent) {
            // should be an array with types
            if (is_array($compontent['types']) && !empty($compontent['types'])) {
                foreach ($compontent['types'] as $type) {
                    if ($type == 'administrative_area_level_2') {
                        return $compontent['long_name'];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
echo getAdministrativeAreaLevel2($jsondata['results']);
```